# How do I find probability function?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable. The probability function is given in the following table

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
x&-10&1&5&10\\ \hline
f(x)&0.1&0.3&0.4&0.2
\end{array}
$$

How do I find the probability function of the discrete random variable $Y$ such that $Y=g(X)=X^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to square the $x$ values. The probabilities stay the same. The probability mass function of $Y$ is

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
y&100&1&25&100\\ \hline
f(x)&0.1&0.3&0.4&0.2
\end{array}
$$

but since $10^2 = -10^2 =100$, this becomes

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
y&100&1&25\\ \hline
f(x)&0.3&0.3&0.4
\end{array}
$$

An alternative way to express this

$$ P_{Y}(y)=  
\begin{cases} 
0.3 & y =1 \\
0.4 & y=25 \\
0.3 & y=100 \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Can you add more details? I do not understand.

Comment: What I do not understand is that why when you square $x$ values, the probabilities do not change?